# how to have jslider's track below the knob's image and how to fill colours in track on Slider's knob movement?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

HI All,

i need to put jSlider's track below the knob's image and fill different colours in track on Slider's knob movement.

Please explain with some code snippets.

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: I really apologize for that. I did not know about how to accept answers. Now i have accepted answers given to me. Please see if could suggest something for my above problem.

Answer (score 1):

That all falls in the realm of Look And Feel (LAF). The LAF in use controls how the component is rendered. So, a GTK LAF will present it so it looks like the rest of GTK, the WinXP LAF will give it the Windows XP appearance, etc.

The best bet for the look you describe is the Synth LAF which reads an xml file to configure how it should present the control.

Here is an IBM developerWorks article on using [Synth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-synth/). And, here is a [blog post by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2005/08/18/synth-subtleties/) on some of the gotchas encountered using Synth. In particular, the comments about skinning a scroll bar may apply to a slider as well.

Comment: The articles link was removed!